# Login form in Iframe not loading

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, authentication

I have a login form inside an iframe. Here is the code for the main page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta content="text/html; charset=windows-1252" http-equiv="content-type">
        <script language="javascript">
            function SubmitForm() {
                document.getElementById('loginframe').contentWindow.document.getElementById('login').submit();
            }
        </script>
        <title>Login to Vote</title>
    </head>
     <body>
        <iframe id="loginframe" src="sasloginhandler.html"></iframe>
        <input onclick="SubmitForm()" value="Submit form" type="button">
    </body>
</html>
```

And here is the code for the "sasloginhandler.html" page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta content="text/html; charset=windows-1252" http-equiv="content-type">
    <title>Login to Vote</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form action="https://moodle.standrews-de.org/login/index.php" method="post"
      id="login">
      <div class="loginform">
        <div class="form-input"> <input name="username" placeholder="Username"
            id="username"
            size="15"
            type="text">
        </div>
        <div class="form-input"> <input name="password" placeholder="Password"
            id="password"
            size="15"
            value=""
            type="password">
          <input id="loginbtn" value="Login" type="submit"> </div>
      </div>
      <div class="forgetpass"><a href="forgot_password.php">Forgotten your
          username or password?</a></div>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

The problem is, neither the submit button inside the iframe nor the javascript submit button outside the iframe does anything. I have tested the iframe code on its own and it works fine, so it seems to be some part of the iframe that is causing the issue. However, I don't know why this would be.

Thank you!

Comment: The iframe code runs in its own compartment, I thought, so you can't affect it by adding buttons outside the iframe.

Comment: Maybe, but even the login button inside the iframe doesn't work... it seems like the iframe is somehow blocked from reloading.

Answer (score 0):

The id of the form in the iframe is `login` but you try to get it with `loginform`

```
document.getElementById('loginframe').contentWindow.document.getElementById('login').submit();
```

Comment: Thanks, that was a stupid mistake. However, it still doesn't work.